# How view different categorized articles in cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a blog website. There are 3 different categories in my database: art, technology, design.

I want to show the last added article for each category. I mean:

```
ART                       TECHNOLOGY                DESIGN
last articles             last article              last article
```

In ActionResult, sended all articles here:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   using (MvcBlogContext context = new MvcBlogContext())
   {
      List<Article> article= context.Article.ToList();
      return View(article);
   }
}
```

How to code to view for each category's last article in cshtml?

Comment: What field in database should be used to identify the last article? Do you have some datetime which stores when the article was created?

Comment: Sure, article has a datetime which stores when article has createn.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `Grouping` according to `Category` then `SelectMany` to select from each category after ordering by `CreationDate` desc. and `Take` top 1 of each category
as following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   using (MvcBlogContext context = new MvcBlogContext())
   {
      List<Article> article= context.Article.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                            .SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreationDate).Take(1)).ToList();
      return View(article);
   }
}
```

Comment: This code looks better to return. But I am failed in "View" part. How to view this three articles in .cshtml using Model?

Comment: Do you want to render it in table each category article displayed in row?

Comment: No, it's gonna be Index page. Gonna be article header, creation date, image etc. Here is a sample html code that not implemented in MVC.
[sample image](https://i.imgur.com/WejiAMn.png)

Comment: in this List<Article> article you passed to view it has 3 records you can iterate on it using for @foreach (var article in Model)